# Finding $\sup$ of the given function in Ball of radius $1$ centered at origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the the supremum of $\dfrac{|x|^{2/3}-|y|^{2/3}}{|x-y|^{2/3}} $ in the unit ball centered at the origin . Here $x\neq y$, $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$.
How do I proceed ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By a modification of the triangular inequality you see that $$||x|^{2/3}-|y|^{2/3}|\leq |x-y|^{2/3}$$ for all $x\neq y$. So we have$$\dfrac{|x|^{2/3}-|y|^{2/3}}{|x-y|^{2/3}}\leq 1$$ Is the value of the function $=1$ at some point?

Comment: Yup at $x=0, y=1$ .

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: @SimonMarkett : Yup :) . thanks a ton .

Comment: Btw it's $x=1$, $y=0$. @did I had to look up maieutics...but thx ;)